# Formatting the output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried this approach:

```
print((i, j) for i in [0,x] for j in [0, y] if (i+j)!=n)
```

where `x`,`y`,`n` are integers.
Formatting the output in python from `[(1,2) , (2,3)]` to `[[1,2], [2,3]]`

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `(` to `[` (and wrap it in a list constructor to print the list, rather than the generator).

```
print(list([i, j] for i in [0,x] for j in [0, y] if (i+j)!=n))
```

Answer (score 0):

And you're getting output of `<generator object at ...>`, because that's the only argument you supply the generator expression. Either turn it into a list comp and unpack it to print:

```
print(*[(i, j) for i in [0,x] for j in [0, y] if (i+j)!=n])
```

or create the generator first, iterate through it and print out its results.